# Suppose you have a 500x500 grid, you need to form squares of size 20x20. How many such squares can you form in the grid, with a step (stride) of 5?

Tags: logic

If the step was 1, one could say the answer is (500-20+1)^2. But with this step of 5, how do  calculate?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean by "step size"?

Comment: Should've called as just 'step'. Also called stride.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you mean by 'stride' correctly, you could just "scale down" by a factor of $5$; the grid size would then be $100 \times 100$, the squares would be $4 \times 4$, and the stride would be size $1$. Then use the same formula you used before to get $\,(100-4+1)^2\,$.

More generally, in an $\,n \times n\,$ grid, forming $\,m \times m\,$ squares with a stride size of $\,k,\,$ the number of squares would be

$$\left(\left\lfloor{\frac{n-m}{k}}\right\rfloor + 1\right)^2$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't frame the question accurately, so apologies.